# electron quick start application not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, electron

I'm new to `electron` and trying to follow different tutorials. Currently I'm following this link to [Write my First Electron App](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/v0.37.4/docs/tutorial/quick-start.md)

my `app` is structured like this

```
your-app/
 ├── package.json
 ├── main.js
 └── index.html
```

The format of `package.json` is

```
 {
  "name"    : "your-app",
  "version" : "0.1.0",
  "main"    : "main.js"
}
```

this is my `main.js`

```
'use strict';

const electron = require('electron');
const app = electron.app;  // Module to control application life.
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;  // Module to create native browser window.

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
var mainWindow = null;

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function() {
  // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform != 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
app.on('ready', function() {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600});

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html');

  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainWindow.on('closed', function() {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    mainWindow = null;
  });
});
```

the `index.html` is the web page I want to show:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    We are using node <script>document.write(process.versions.node)</script>,
    Chrome <script>document.write(process.versions.chrome)</script>,
    and Electron <script>document.write(process.versions.electron)</script>.
  </body>
</html>
```

Now when I run `electron` command in my app's source directory, it shows this

[image: this]

instead of this result

[image: instead]

Every time I've to drag my `index.html` to the empty space of first image to get the result like second image.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Please help me out where am I wrong in this simple application. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: what parameters are you passing to electron?

Comment: nothing. I just write 'electron'

Comment: you need to pass your file name, follow the help in the image shown.

Comment: it gives error when I pass file name with electron

Comment: @dandavis your point solved my problem. by passing htlm file as parameter to electron resolved my issue.

Comment: @dandavis you can post your comment as answer so I could mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have to run `electron index.html` to resolve this issue.

Comment: This is not documented anywhere in the web. Was very frustrating as I wasted at least half a day. You saved the rest of the time. Thanks!

Comment: I had also to run this in windows. I think it's only for windows. In Mac and Linux I could run `electron .`

Answer (score 6):

You must pass the directory where your package.json resides as argument to the electron command.
So if you are executing electron from inside your app dir you have to write

```
electron .
```

Comment: no..even from inside my app...I have to run electron index.html to execute it

Comment: @NailaAkbar For me it was the otherway: `electron index.html` does not work, while `electron .` does.

Comment: (but putting the `main.js` file does work as well)

Answer (score 4):

if you do not provide any parameter when running 'electron' command, rename main.js to index.js (which electron runs as default)

Comment: changing file name didn't resolve my issue. but passing .html file as paramter resolved it.